# Problem with delegates removing annotation

Tags: swift, xcode, annotations, mapkit

I have two screens. The first one (firstViewController) has a mapView with a UITapGestureRecognizer. When the user taps the screen, an annotations is added to the map and the second screen (secondViewController) is presented.

When the user dismisses the secondViewController and comes back to the first one, the annotation should be removed. I know I have to use delegation, but I just can't make it to work.

This is the code I have now:

```
class firstViewController: UIViewController, AnnotationDelegate {
    
    let mapView = MKMapView()

    var temporaryPinArray = [MKPointAnnotation]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(mapView
        
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        mapView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        secondVC.annotationDelegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        mapView.frame = view.bounds
    }
    
    @objc func handleTap(_ gestureReconizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = gestureReconizer.location(in: mapView)
        let coordinates = mapView.convert(location, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)       
        
                let pin = MKPointAnnotation()
        pin.coordinate = coordinates
        
        temporaryPinArray.removeAll()
        temporaryPinArray.append(pin)
        mapView.addAnnotations(temporaryPinArray)

                // Present secondViewController
        let secondVC = SecondViewController()
        panel.set(contentViewController: secondVC)
        panel.addPanel(toParent: self)
    }

        func didRemoveAnnotation(annotation: MKPointAnnotation) {
        mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```

**Second View Controller**

```
    protocol AnnotationDelegate {
        func didRemoveAnnotation(annotation: [MKPointAnnotation])
    }

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var annotationDelegate: AnnotationDelegate!
    
    let mainVC = firstViewController()
    
    let closeButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .grey
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(closeButton)
        
        closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissPanel), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        closeButton.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width-50, y: 10, width: 30, height: 30)
    }
    
    @objc func dismissPanel() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        annotationDelegate.didRemoveAnnotation(annotation: mainVC.temporaryPinArray)
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a new instance of `firstViewController` inside `SecondViewController`. This instance is unrelated to the actual first one:

```
let mainVC = firstViewController()
```

This means that `temporaryPinArray` is different as well. So instead of passing in this unrelated array...

```
@objc func dismissPanel() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    annotationDelegate.didRemoveAnnotation(annotation: mainVC.temporaryPinArray)
}
```

Just change the function to take no parameters instead:

```
protocol AnnotationDelegate {
    func didRemoveAnnotation() /// no parameters
}

@objc func dismissPanel() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    annotationDelegate.didRemoveAnnotation() /// no parameters
}
```

And inside `firstViewController`'s `didRemoveAnnotation`, reference the actual `temporaryPinArray`.

```
func didRemoveAnnotation() {
    mapView.removeAnnotations(temporaryPinArray) /// the current array
}
```

Comment: I've done what you told me, but when I try to dismiss the secondViewController, the app crashes. It says: "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" on the line of annotationDelegate.didRemoveAnnotation()

Comment: @danicode make sure you are doing `secondVC.annotationDelegate = self`. Also, do `annotationDelegate?.didRemoveAnnotation()` with the `?` to avoid force unwrapping/crash

Comment: I really think I have all set up as I should. But when I dismiss the second view controller the pin is still on the map. I don't know where the problem is ;(

Comment: @danicode just realized. Can you post the code for how you are presenting `secondVC`? You need to set the delegate there.

Comment: thank you so much!! I realize now that the problem was that i was setting the delegate in viewDidLoad instead of the function that presents `secondVC`. I can't thank you enough because I was trying to solve this problem too much time now. Thank you!!